# What is the time complexity to access/find HashMap bucket(Not value in bucket)?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Suppose we have two different hashMaps, say map1 and map2.

- map1 has 1000 entries with 1000 buckets.
- map2 has 999999 entries with 999999 buckets.

And suppose, we have an object "obj1" with hashCode "1234" and we put this object as a key in both map1 and map2(with value "xyz").

Will it require more time to find "obj1" value in map2?
Will the time complexity be still O(1) for accessing obj1 from both map1 and map2?

Comment: Why do you think it would be different? Finding the hash bucket given a hashcode is a modulo operation and an array access. Neither of those cost more if you use bigger numbers. There are obviously factors that influence it much more, like how many hashcode collisions there are (do all objects in the map have the same hashcode?)

Comment: @Krease -  In HashMap, it creates array to hold hashcode, we call them as Arrayof HashCodes/Buckets. So If I want to find hashcode from that Array, I still needs to traverse through it right?

Comment: You don’t “traverse” through the array of buckets, you do a modulo operation on the hash with the number of buckets - his gives you they bucket the object lives in. If you have _collisions_ (multiple objects in the bucket), then you traverse through that. Your question doesn’t specify anything about collisions though

Comment: Yes. I got your point.You mean to say "hashcode % sizeOfmap"
 right?

Comment: Yes. The `%` character is the modulo operation in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the bucket is O(1) in a `HashMap`, always, independent of the capacity (number of buckets).

Let's say your `obj1` has a hash code of `1234567`. The core of a `HashMap` is not to search for the correct bucket (as a TreeMap would do), but to compute its position, and immediately access the bucket with that number. That's where the hash code comes into the game.

The computation is `obj.hashCode() % capacity`, and the resulting number gives the index into the `bucketsArray`.

- For the small hash map, it's `1234567 % 1000` = `567`, meaning that the relevant bucket is `bucketsArray[567]`.
- For the big one, it's `1234567 % 999999` = `234568`, resulting in `bucketsArray[234568]`.

The time necessary for computing the division rest is constant, independent of the values. The time for accessing an array with a given index is constant as well, so it's O(1).

We have only talked about finding the bucket. If the bucket contains multiple entries, a linear search completes the hash map access, and that's O(K) with K being the (average? maximum?) number of entries in a bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I thin it would be best to answer with a code and diagram. We all know what hashing (one way) function  is it is. Basically it takes arbitrary input and returns number (in java it is int but that is not always the case). And int in java has 32 bits. That means that it can be between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. Every object on every java heep that exist can calculate it's hash (using method from java.util.Object class) and it has to be in that interval.

Now let's assume that we have 3 objects.

```
21234 = obj1.hashCode();  
623424 = obj2.hashCode();
23124432 = obj3.hasCode();
```

and we want to add them to a hashMap that has 200 buckets. (this is not a working java code i typed it here)

```
public class MyHashMap {
    private final Buckets[] buckets = new Buckets[200];

    public boolean add(Object object){
        int resultModulo = object.hashCode() % 200;
        buckets[buckets].add(object);
    } 
}
```

Now for the final peace. For our object the `resultModulo` will be 34(21234), 24(623424), 32(23124432). And the calculate number will not exceed 200.

Array is allocated as a continuous piece of memory. Just array of pointers(64-bits) not the actual objects. So the bucktes[] looks something like that

```
0xB80000xB80020xB80670xC1101 ....
1      2      3      4       .... 200
```

and so when your code invokes bucket[34],bucket[24],bucket[32] what the hardware does is this:

```
  mov eax, bucktes[ecx*19] 
  ; eax now contains the pointer to the
  ; 19 element in the array
  ; this is a one clock instruction
```

So that is why it doesn't matter how many bucket you have.